# How to connect to postgresql database using shell script

Tags: shell, psql

I want to write a shell script to run these commands. I usually connect from terminal using commands as below

```
    //first go to the directory 
     cd /opt/novell/sentinel/3rdparty/postgresql/bin/
    // then type following
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/novell/sentinel/3rdparty/postgresql/lib/
    // then fire following command 
     ./psql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5432 --dbname=SIEM --username=dbauser
     Password for user dbauser: ****
```

Comment: So, you are OK with your password being stored in the shell script?

Comment: no i don't want to store password in my script

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why don't you update your PATH and export LD_LIBRARY_PATH permanently, by adding to your `.profile` these lines:

```
PATH=/opt/novell/sentinel/3rdparty/postgresql/bin/:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/novell/sentinel/3rdparty/postgresql/lib/
```

Then use the script to connect DB as simple as following

```
#!/bin/sh
psql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --dbname=SIEM --username=dbauser
```

After you run the script, you will be asked about the password.

If you would like not to enter password every time, you can use the password file .pgpass (see [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html)  for details), just add to your `~/.pgpass` the following line:

```
127.0.0.1:5432:SIEM:dbauser:your_password
```

Be safe, dissallow any access to world or group:

```
chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass.
```

After this, you can connect to your db by using script above without password prompt.

Comment: where do i create .pgpass file

Comment: @GauravRajput, `.pgpass` file usually is located in your home directory, or in a directory defined by PGPASSFILE environmental variable.

Comment: I had created this .pgpass file under root and then it worked fine.thank you very much

Comment: i get this error "/usr/bin/postgres : option invalide -- 'U'"